# Changing title colour in error messages

Tags: java, joptionpane

I am using the following to display an error message:

```
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(myFrame, "Please enter data into the Name field.", "Missing Data", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

I want to change the background colour of the title. I tried setting the OptionPane.errorDialog.titlePane.background in the UIManager but that didn't work

```
UIManager.put("OptionPane.errorDialog.titlePane.background", Color.GREEN);
```